# Is there a way to get the MAC address of a Wi-Fi device in Linux without using automatic tools?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I want to know if there is a method to obtain a MAC address of a protected (WPA2) Wi-Fi hotspot or network without using Aircrack-ng , aAirdump-ng, etc. but rather by some basic command.

Answer (score 4):

The BSSID can usually be retrieved by just asking the OS to scan for available access points, since it is basic information required to *connect*, after all.

On modern Linux systems with 'iw' installed, that would be

```
iw wlan0 scan
```

(This will cause a new scan. If you only need cached results, it's `iw wlan0 scan dump`.)

With NetworkManager, `nmcli` can also show this information:

```
nmcli -f "in-use,ssid,mode,chan,rate,signal,bars,security,bssid" dev wifi list
```

(This always uses cached results.)